# Testmethod verification that @future published Platform Event

Tags: unit-test, platform-event

Given an `@future` method

```
public class MyClass {
  @future
  public static void doPublishAsFuture(){
    EventBus.publish(new My_Platform_Event__e());
  }
}
```

and a testmethod

```
@isTest
private static void testPlatEventPublishViaFuture() {
  Test.startTest();
  MyClass.doPublishAsFuture();
  Test.stoptest();
  // How to know if event(s) were published?
  System.assertEquals(1,Limits.getDmlRows()); // fails, actual value = 0!
}
```

So, assuming I don't have (or want) a trigger to consume the Platform Event and save in some `Log__c` SObject, how do I verify the Platform Events were actually published?

> N.B. recording in a static variable within the class that the publish
>   was successful and interrogating in the testmethod does not seem like
>   a great solution.

Comment: Just curious, why would you publish them from a future? Also, it should consume a DML. Maybe it's similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/76782/2995).

Comment: @AdrianLarson - (1) yes, publishing `PlatformEvents` does consume DML but the limits are reset after Test.stopTest() - which is needed to start the @future so the value is not assertable. (2) PlatformEvents are not part of a transaction so it would seem that best practice would be to publish at the end of the transaction - and the future would never execute if the transaction aborted. (3) I'm using future as a fallback in case queueables are exhausted

Comment: Without platform level support for mocking Platform Events I suspect an Apex trigger is the only way to interact with them in a testing context.

Comment: I've raised it on the [Platform Events success community group](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003EtJ0Y). If you don't care about the Database.SaveResult you could just maintain your own static count ever time `EventBus.publish` is called. It's not pretty, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you validate it within the future method?

I hate putting test validation in classes, but if you need it absolutely....

```
if( test.isRunningTest() ){
    System.assertEquals( 1, Limits.getDmlRows() );
}
```

It would only execute within a test instance, so shouldn't affect your code execution otherwise. I just don't like it because I think it is dirty coding.

Comment: Thanks -- that said, I would never put validation within the class; besides this doesn't prove that the future method was ever invoked and that it published a Platform Event. Daniel Ballinger's last comment is a better solution and one I considered but classes shouldn't have to register their action in a static variable for inspection by the testmethod.